# Apple Transit API integrating

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I heard a lot about apples new transit api. Im wanting to integrate this into my app. I basically want to find the geolocation information of transit information within the proximity of the user.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or is it for a totally different purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an iOS 6 api, which is in beta - therefore you & we cannot discuss it in a public forum, it contravenes your NDA as an Apple Developer.

You can ask Apple themselves, however - through their support channels.